# Sending email from a 'Contact Us' UIViewController iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, email

Is there a way to send email directly from an iOS app on Xcode without showing the email dialog screen for a built in "contact us" form? There is a ton of stuff on this on SO but it all says that either it's not allowed (at least through Apple-compliant frameworks), or the ones that say it is allowed have not worked for me in any capacity. Is this allowed or not, because I can't seem to fight any answer that isn't riddled with ambiguity, argument and controversy. Thanks!

Comment: If you already found "tons of stuff" stating that this is not possible, what new answer do you expect? - And can you point to any answer claiming that it *is* possible?

Comment: It is not allow. No ambiguity now.

Comment: Just FYI, if it is not allowed (through Applie-compliant frameworks), then the app WILL be rejected from the App Store even if you somehow find a workaround with private libraries. If you come across answers that say it's not apple-compliant, then that's a sign to immediately stop searching.

Comment: @Byte - Thank you. Yes, a lot of people claimed to be able to do it using the UIMessage kit and provided more or less the same code but I tried it all and it did not work...now I know it's a waste of time.

Comment: You could do this by creating an api on your own server where you pass the necessary data to and send the email from the server. This is also possible for sms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't send email without showing to the user the corresponding view controller for mail. Same way for SMSs.